# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, converters, retrofit2, gson

I have cross checked a lot of reference before actually asking the question. As most people I am calling a web service and and getting the above result. My problem is rather more specific, so before asking let me add my `code snippet`

```
public static WebService getRestService(String newApiBaseUrl, String accessToken)
    {
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();


        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        }


        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        restBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(newApiBaseUrl)
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));

        if (accessToken != null) {
            AuthenticationInterceptor interceptor =
                    new AuthenticationInterceptor(accessToken);

            if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(interceptor)) {
                httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);

                restBuilder.client(httpClient.build());
            }
        }

        retrofit = restBuilder.build();
        return retrofit.create(WebService.class);
    }
```

Please ignore the interpreter. This is my service generator class through which all web service is called. I am calling a POST method which will return me a simple response.

I can see my correct response in "Android Monitor". But when its passes through JsonConverterFactory, it gives me above error. One thing I know for sure that web service is returning a simple text response as there is nothing specific to return to application. Is there a way by which I can convert my text response to class. Please free shout back if I missed anything.

Also adding my interface method

```
@Headers({
            Constants.ApiHeader.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON
    })

    @POST("POST_URL/{number}")
    Call<MyResponseModel> getActualProductLocation(@Header("access_token") String accessToken, @Path("number") String number, @Body List<MyRequestModel> body);
```

**Update**
I managed to get a part of code snippet from server. This is what their response look like:

```
Response.status(200).entity("Response Success").build()
```

Comment: Post `MyResponseModel`. Most possibly it is not in the right format.

Comment: Its empty as there is no key value pair returned by server(JSON data).Do I have to define any string variable in the class?

Comment: *My problem is rather more specific* how so? These problems are all the same: the json data is not what the converter expected. It's posible the gson converter does not find a lone string valid json (it is, though)

Comment: @Android, server returns you empty string.

Comment: its returning me something "Response success"

Comment: @TimCastelijns Here I know server is returning simple text and not JSON, so I have to consume text instead of converting JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Because the backend doesn't reply you with JSON formatted data, you have to handle it with custom converter.

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/tomkoptel/35ea8dca7fca040d63f3#file-stringconverterfactory-md) an example of a custom converter that would fulfil your needs.

A snippet from **StringConverterFactory.java**

```
...
private static class StringConverter implements Converter<String> {
    private static final MediaType PLAIN_TEXT = MediaType.parse("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

    @Override
    public String fromBody(ResponseBody body) throws IOException {
        return new String(body.bytes());
    }

    @Override
    public RequestBody toBody(String value) {
        return RequestBody.create(PLAIN_TEXT, convertToBytes(value));
    }

    private static byte[] convertToBytes(String string) {
        try {
            return string.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
...
```

And then when creating your `Retrofit`:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
   ...
   .addConverterFactory(StringConverterFactory.create());
   ...
   .build();
```

Comment: Hey Thanks buddy, I will try it out. I have one question. If I start using custom converter, I assume I still would be able to use my general converter, and it would not interfere with my existing converter. Is that right?

Comment: You can have one converter per Retrofit instance. You cannot change them dynamically. If you want to have different converters, you have to initialize different Retrofit instances with that converters.

Comment: I am having issue with imports. Are these classes belong to retrofit? Package like `import retrofit2.Converter;`

Comment: [Converter](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Converter.html) comes with Retrofit's package.